# c++ class refers to each other

Tags: c++, class

I have a class

```
class PCB {
     public: 
     struct {
         string type;
         **linklist list;**//refer to list which contains PCB instance
     } status;
}
```

what i want is to create the class PCB instance, but the instance is in a linklist list. i build the linklist class as below

```
class linklist
{

   public:

     void append( PCB num );
};
void linklist::append(PCB num){
}
```

Error occus saying **num** above is in error type. what shall i do in this case?

Comment: Are these in the same file?  Can you give the specific error message?

Comment: Why are you writing your own linked list instead of using `std::list`?

Comment: @Wyzard: A typical (homework) exercise or interview prep?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. You can use forward declaration:

   ```
   class linklist; // forward declaration

   class PCB {

     public:
        struct {
           string type;
           linklist list;  //refer to list which contains PCB instance
       } status;
   }
   ```
2. Or when you only refer to a type by reference or by pointer, you do not need to include it's header file.

   ```
   linklist* list
   ```

Comment: http://ideone.com/v8Mv6 The forward declaration has to go in the _other_ file.  It can't go in the PCB file.

Comment: Also, in the first example `linklist` cannot be forward-declared since  no reference or pointer is used.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need the copy in your `linklist::append` method you could as well just use a (`const`) reference

```
void append(const PCB& num);
```

and forward declare `PCB` before in the same header file

```
class PCB;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a forward declaration on one of the types but your really should ask yourself why you are doing this.

I cannot think of any time when this would be a good idea.  If you think about your problem relative to the real world linklist is a collection of buckets.  What you are asking for is a bucket (PCB) to hold a series (linklist) of buckets (PCB).  In reality this would never work as a bucket cannot hold a collection of other buckets of the same size.

Another think to ask yourself, why would you use a link list when the STL (Standard Template Library) provides everything you would need and more already.  I would highly recommend a vector if you list of PCB's are fairly static, or a list if not.

Linked lists can be very efficient for lightweight containers but you have to maintain them.  If you using classes, GO WITH STL containers.

Comment: i will take your suggestion. i think i may recheck my code and try to improve

Answer (score -1):

You need to forward-declare each class before defining the other.  In the header that defines `PCB`, write

```
class linklist;
```

before the definition of `PCB`, and in the header that defines `linklist`, write

```
class PCB;
```

before the definition of `linklist`.  That way, when the compiler encounters each of the class definitions, it'll know that the "other" class's name is valid and let you declare pointers to it even though it hasn't been fully defined yet.

**Edit:**  Sorry, I just noticed that your `linklist::append` function actually takes a `PCB` instance, not a pointer.  In that case you need to make sure that the `PCB` class is defined before `linklist`, but you still need to forward-declare `linklist` before `PCB` so that you can make pointers to it.  The order of your code should be:

```
class linklist;

class PCB {
  // involves pointers to linklist
;

class linklist {
  // holds instances of PCB
};
```

**Edit Again:**  I's misread your `**linklist list` as a pointer to a `linklist` (even though it's syntactically wrong).

What you need to do is:

- Forward-declare `PCB` so that the definition of `linklist` can refer to it in a method signature.
- Define the `linklist` class, but not its `append` function yet.
- Define the `PCB` class, which can contain an instance of `linklist` since that class is now fully-defined.
- Define the `linklist::append()` function, which can take an instance of `PCB` since that class is now fully-defined.

That'll get your code to compile, but it won't do what you probably want it to, because the way you've defined your classes doesn't make much sense.  Your `PCB` class doesn't "refer" to a list, it *contains a list* within it.  Since that `list` member variable isn't a pointer, *every `PCB` instance contains an entire `linklist`*.  When you `append()` a `PCB` to a `linklist`, you're making a copy of that whole `PCB`, including the (different) `linklist` that it contains.

I have a feeling you're coming from Java or C# and you're assuming that things are references when they really aren't.  You need to learn about how to use pointers.

Comment: You won't be able to declare a full `PCB` if all you have is a forward declaration. They only help for pointers to or references of `PCB`s.

Comment: thanks all for giving forward declare suggestion, as i can only choose one correct answer, i will give it to the first one suggest the answer, thanks a lot

Comment: Since `PCB` contains an actual `linklist` member, foward declaration won't help there.

Comment: Hmm, good point.  I misread the double asterisk as being a pointer rather than just emphasis.